# CartoDB Density View

Tags: carto, cartocss

Is the Density View for CartoDB no longer working? I have looked at three datasets on multiple accounts, and none of them are working correctly. They show only 1 bucket color, no matter the density. The CSS is only generating one grouping for the point density, so obviously it is not generating the correct CSS. I can manually manipulate it (the CSS), but requires a lot of fine tuning to find the right grouping!

If anyone knows something I could be doing wrong, please tell me!

Comment: Could you share some link of a visualization where this is happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's working fine for me, I just made http://cdb.io/S4umB9

You want to download the same data from http://cholmes.cartodb.com/tables/tornados_11/public and see if it works?

If that does but yours doesn't then maybe it's your data. Did you set the data type of the column to bucket to a Number? If you give me the public data link I can put it in my account and play with it.